# How to use mod_Rewrite to check multiple folders for a static file

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

What are the mod_Rewrite rules for checking multiple folder locations for a given file.  For instance, if I have a folder structure of:

```
public/
    css/
    library1/
        css/
    library2/
        css/
```

and I want requests to `/css/somefile.css` to first check the `public/css/` directory, then cascade to `public/library1/css/` then `public/library2/css/`, returning a 404 if an asset cannot be found in any of the directories.

I was thinking along the lines of:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond library1%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ library1$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond library2%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ library2$1 [L]
```

But this doesn't seem to work - I'm not sure how to check for file existence on a dynamically generated path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/library1%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^css/.+ library1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/library2%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^css/.+ library2%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: Cheers for that - I didn't spot the %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} variable when reading the docs.

Comment: @DavidWinterbottom: You need the absolute filesystem path when you want to test for existing files, directories etc. *REQUEST\_FILENAME* does already contain the absolute filesystem path but *REQUEST\_URI* only the absolute URL path.

Comment: @Gumbo: shouldn't line 6 reference `library2`?

Answer (score 1):

[RewriteMap Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) might help.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the server variables do not contain what you think. Try increase the logging to debug, so you can see exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Loads files from production server
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (library1|library2)/(.*)$ http://production.com/$1/$2 [R=302,L,NC]
```

To achieve this:

something.dev/**library1**/style.css -> production.com/**library1**/*style.css*
something.dev/**library2**/*vendor/css/style.css* -> production.com/**library2**/*vendor/css/style.css*