# Apache .htaccess retry other directory if file not found

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i need a htaccess rewrite rule for my apache webserver that searches in other directories if a file has not been found.

if

```
http://domain.com/x.jpg
```

is not found, look in

```
http://domain.com/bla/x.jpg
```

if not there then look in

```
http://domain.com/foo/x.jpg
```

and so on.

i am trying the following but it doesnt work. still gives me 404s

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|apk|bmp|webp))$ /foo/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|apk|bmp|webp))$ /bla/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176628/how-to-use-mod-rewrite-to-check-multiple-folders-for-a-static-file

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles I think this is duplicate. Nice find.

Comment: if i try what is suggested in the other question, i get a 404

Comment: @clamp: show us how you ave try the answer of this other question, you may have missed something there. But that answer seems valid and if you do not add details your question will get closed as duplicate.

Comment: @regilero i already posted what i am trying.

Comment: I see nothing in your post which looks like the linked solution. So we cannot check if you applied the solution the right way.

Comment: @clamp: You need to use conditions like this: `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/foo/$1 -f [NC]` before `RewriteRule`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with you're current config, is that it always does the first rewrite if the file doesn't exist and the second rewrite never get's executed. You will need to check for existence of the file before doing the redirection such as below

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)(/.+\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|apk|bmp|webp))$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1/bla%2 -f
RewriteRule . %1/bla%2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)(/.+\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|apk|bmp|webp))$ 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1/foo%2 -f
RewriteRule . %1/foo%2 [L]
```

Comment: thanks but that gives me an internatl server error. shouldnt there be another slash after the directory name?

Comment: In my tests REQUEST_URI has a forward slash as the first character so it shouldn't be needed. Are you redirecting from the root directory or subdirectory?  The code works for the root directory only. If you need it to work in a subdirectory I can modify it

Comment: it should work from the root directory, however the lookup directory could be made up of several directories. e.g. /foo/bar/test/bla/ starting from root.

Comment: didnt realise it was meant for all directories. will modify accordingly

Comment: Yeah it seemed that my original answer had an extra ). But I've updated it accordingly, see if this works