# .htaccess check if file exists in multiple sub-folders and rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Let's suppose that I have a static website on Apache server with this folders structure:

```
http://www.example.com
|    
+-- /news/
|  |  
|  +-- page1.html
|  +-- page2.html
|  +-- ...
|
+-- /otherstuff/
```

The url of the pages inside the /news/ folder is:

```
http://www.example.com/news/page1.html  
http://www.example.com/news/page2.html
```

Now, the number of files in the /news/ folder is growing and I would like to create new subfolders inside /news/ and split files across these new dirs, but I also want to hide the subfolders names in the urls.

The new folders structure will be:

```
http://www.example.com
|    
+-- /news/
|  |  
|  +-- /subfolder1/
|  |   |
|  |   +-- page1.html
|  |
|  +-- /subfolder2/
|  |   |
|  |   +-- page2.html
|  +-- ...
|
+-- /otherstuff/
```

but **the urls of the pages have to remain the same**:

```
http://www.example.com/news/page1.html  
http://www.example.com/news/page2.html
```

and **not**:

```
http://www.example.com/news/subfolder1/page1.html  
http://www.example.com/news/subfolder2/page2.html
```

Is there a way to achive this result using rewrite rules in .htaccess?

I've read this question:
[How to use mod_Rewrite to check multiple folders for a static file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176628/how-to-use-mod-rewrite-to-check-multiple-folders-for-a-static-file)

but the accepted answer does not work for me.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the following rule in /news/.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subfolder/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\.html$ /news/subfolder/$1 [L]
```

This will rewrite **/news/file.html** to **/news/subfolder/file.html** if file.html exists in **/news/subfolder/** .

If your htaccess is in root, you can try the following

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/news/subfolder/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^news/(.*?)\.html$ /news/subfolder/$1.html [L]
```

If the examples above fail, you can try this in root or news/.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?:news/)?(.*?)\.html$ /news/subfolder/$1.html [L]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I tried your code but still no luck: the url /news/file.html gives a 404 even if the file in /news/subfolder/file.html exists. I'm starting to think that there is something wrong in server variables, because if I go to /news/subfolder/news1.html the code %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/news/subfolder/$1.html  becomes C:/xampp/htdocs/news/subfolder/news/subfolder/file.html

Comment: Yes, thats the problem on some servers. I will post a working solution for you.

Comment: You did it! Now it works, thanks a lot!! Just another little question: is it possible to also redirect /news/subfolder/xxx.html to /news/xxx.html?